# Scroll back to original pre-keyboard position after keyboard closes

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user taps in a textarea, the keyboard appears and (if necessary) scrolls the page up such that both the `textarea` and the keyboard are visible. What I want is for the page to scroll back down to where it was originally before the keyboard appeared.

I have tried:

1. User taps in `textarea`,
2. Use `focus` or `focusin` listeners to get `scrollTop()` BEFORE the keyboard appears. **PROBLEM**: these only fire after the keyboard appears, and the scroll has changed,
3. Keyboard appears. Page is scrolled up so keyboard and `textarea` are both visible,
4. User closes keyboard,
5. Use `focusout` or `blur` to set `scrollTop()` back to what it was in step 2.

The issue is that I can't get `scrollTop()` before the keyboard appears. `focus` and `focusin` fire AFTER the keyboard appears.

Comment: How do you display the keyboard ? You should call it AFTER the get `scrollTop()` at step 2.